# How to transfer funds via Currency(Balance Pallet) in ink! smart contract?

Tags: pallet, ink, balances

In ink! smart contract, we usually use AccountID and save the balances in array using mapping or HashMap. This is the traditional way of ERC20 smart contract.

I am now developing on my local chain, and main token is MMM.

What I want is to transfer our own token (MMM) via smart contract, not deployed token.

Is my idea correct? and can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to invoke a function in your smart contract that transfers your native chain token to another account.

In ink! there is the function [`ink_env::transfer`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.transfer.html) to do this.

You can take a look at the `give_me` function in our [`contract-transfer`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/contract-transfer/lib.rs) example, it does exactly this plus some error handling around it.

Comment: How would you transfer the native chain token from one account to another?
I can't find any example for that online, and the example you provided only shows how to transfer a native token from the contract to the caller.

Comment: I know this is old, but for others who bump into this, I think what you were looking at was this:
https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/9e6c800b498c0da74e9a29fe5470696b63fee49f/call-runtime/lib.rs#L97